# Stack smashing error when manipulating array of ints in function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, stack

So I'm trying to make a simple program that takes an array that is partially full and adds an integer to the beginning shifting all existing elements to the right. It seems what I have here adds and shifts things properly but once all the code executes, I get a stack smashing detected error.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void addCommand(int *, int, int);

void main() {
    int i;
    int list[10];
    list[0] = 1;
    list[1] = 5;

    printf("Before add:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", list[i]);
    }

    addCommand(list, sizeof(list), 4);

    printf("Adding 4:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", list[i]);
    }
}


void addCommand(int *arr, int size, int new) {
    int k;
    printf("%d", arr[0]);   
    for (k = size - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
         if (&arr[k] != NULL) {     
            if (k > 0) {        
                arr[k] = arr[k-1];
            } else {
                arr[k] = new;
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

And here's the output:

[image]

If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong here, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Note that the `if (&arr[k] != NULL)` test is pretty much pointless.  It would only be true under arcane circumstances.  The code does not do what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

```
addCommand(list, sizeof(list), 4);
```

above line doesn't pass number of element in list array. you have to do something like this:

```
sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])
```